# Anyone with experience on embedding CINT into a C++ app?

Tags: c++, scripting, root-framework

I'm talking about [ROOT's CINT](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cint).

I've been developing a game in c++ which uses Python for programming the AI. As much as I love Python, and how easy it makes programming the AI (generators and FP are really sexy), it makes non trivial algorithms run *so* slow.

Then I remembered I read somewhere about CINT, and how it can be embeddable. Now I need your help to decide if implement CINT as an alternate scripting system. With python I use Boost::Python, which makes it almost unpainful to expose classes and objects *once you get used to it*. Is there such ease with CINT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written classes compiled against Root, and then accessed them directly in the interpreter. That's easy, though all such classes are expected to derive from `TObject`. What I don't know is if that is a cint requirement or a ROOT requirement. you might be best off asking on the [RootTalk CINT Support forum](http://root.cern.ch/phpBB3/viewforum.php?f=5&sid=4dee99119522f4752c32487362fa2406)

---

To address the questions in the comments:

- The derivation from `TObject` can be second hand: your classes can be derived from something derived from `TObject`, it just has to *be* a TObject.
- Root provides a tool (`makecint`) and some macros (`ClassDef` and `ClassImp`) to support integrating your code with the interpreted execution environment: write your clas deriving it from `TObject`; include the `ClassDef` macro in the header and the `ClassImp` macro in the source file; run `makecint` over the code to generate all the tedious integration nonesense, then compile your code *and* the generated code to a shared object (or, I presume, a dll on a windows box); start the interpreter; load the library with `.L`; and your class is fully integrated with the interpreted environment (tab completion will work and all that). The build can be automated with `make` (and presumable other tools). ##Again,## I don't know how much of this belongs to ROOT and how much to cint. But it is all open source, so you can snag and adapt what you need.

Comment: I think you could make a wrapper class that derives from the same class as your exposed object and TObject. This would avoid modifying your existing classes. BTW, can you elaborate a little more? How difficult was it to include it into your build system? Is it easy to intgrate, to link? I'm quite interested :)